# angular async validator object not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I'm using https://github.com/codekraft-studio/angular-async-validation

and I'm getting this error, and i'm not sure why its not passing data successfully.

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/nameCheck[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

**Route**

```
Route::post('/nameCheck', 'UserController@checkName');
```

here is the server side, im using laravel 5.5

```
public function checkName(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request['name'];

    $existing_name = User::where('name', '=', $name)->first();

    if($existing_name == NULL){
        return 'name does not exists';    
    }
    else{
        return 'name  exist';
    }
}
```

**js**

```
app.directive('nameValidator', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$asyncValidators.name = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return $http.post('/nameCheck' + {
          name: viewValue
        }).then(
          function(response) {
            if (!response.data.validName) {
              return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
            }
            return true;
          }
        );
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="userForm.model.name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" name-validator required autofocus>

    <span ng-if="userForm.name.$pending">
      Checking Username...
    </span>
    @if ($errors->has('name'))
    <span class="help-block">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean, look at your URL

Comment: still not understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `POST` call :

```
$http.post('/nameCheck', {
  name: viewValue
}).then(
  function(response) {
    if (!response.data.validName) {
      return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
    }
    return true;
  }
);
```

The below is wrong :

```
$http.post('/nameCheck'+ {name:viewValue}).then ..
```

Also, please try to add a error callback, if the POST call throws an error you have to catch it in a callback.

Comment: let me test this

Comment: worked like a charm ill mark this as answer as soon as it will let me, thank you